# Django / Python: Generate random timezone respecting datetime within the next 24h

Tags: python, django

I need to generate a random datetime within the next 24 hours (so any hour, minute, and second but within 24h of when the method is run). This will go in a django `model.DateTimeField()`. I know that I can get the current timezone-aware datetime with

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.now()
```

but it's not quite clear to me how to pick a random time 24h into the future from timezone.now().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import datetime
import random
from django.utils import timezone

now = timezone.now()
future = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=random.randint(0, 86400))
```

`future` will then be any random moment between now and 24h from now. The magic number 86400 is simply the number of seconds in a day.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a random number between `0` and `86400` (the number of seconds in 24 hours).

```
from datetime import timedelta
from random import randint

timezone.now() + timedelta(seconds=randint(0, 86400))
```